# How to get excel to update the year each year?

Tags: excel

Currently I am trying to get my Excel spreadsheet to update the age of people as the dates come around. For example, this year I am 20 years old and my birthday is 03/03/1994. I want Excel to be able to change my age to 21 on 03/03/2015 and change it to 22 on 03/03/2016.

I was thinking a formula that involves taking the date of birth and subtracting it from the current date but I don't know how to get excel to update that current date.

This is so that I don't have to go in and change each person's age whenever they have a birthday.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-HP010070467.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your question is `=now()` or `=today()`

However there is a formula in excel called `=DATEDIF()` (literally **date dif** ference)

This takes three arguments (in context):

- Past Date/Birthdate
- To Date/Today
- Interval Type (full years in this case)

So the formula can be written like this:

`=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("01/01/2001"),TODAY(),"y")`

This gives you an answer in whole calendar years

You could of course replace `DATEVALUE("01/01/2001")` with a cell reference

`=DATEDIF(VALUE(A1),TODAY(),"y")`

Comment: Thanks! I was originally using Gary's answer but the "value(A1)" worked so well and is freakin awesome

Answer (score 0):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=DATEDIF(DATEVALUE("3/3/1994"),TODAY(),"y")
```